# How to open URL after scanning QR Code?

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, avcapturesession

I'm working on a project which consist of a QR code reader. As for the output, I would like the App to open the weblink if the QR code is embedded with URL. Example, the app should open Google when I scan a QR code embedded with www.google.com.

The following is my code:

```
class QRScannerController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var messageLabel:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var topbar: UIView!

    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?

    let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video as the media type parameter.
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {
            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

            // Initialize the captureSession object.
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

            // Set the input device on the capture session.
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

            // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

            // Start video capture.
            captureSession?.startRunning()

            // Move the message label and top bar to the front
            view.bringSubview(toFront: messageLabel)
            view.bringSubview(toFront: topbar)

            // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

            if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
                view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
                view.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
            }

        } catch {
            // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

    // MARK: - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate Methods

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
            messageLabel.text = "No QR/barcode is detected"
            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently for now, it only detects and displays the URL in the textview. I would appreciate any helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then take the URL from metadataObj.stringValue and open it ???

Answer (score 0):

Use this to detect the link and open it

```
 let string = "some other text http://www.google.com should detect the link"

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    do{
        let dataDetector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingAllTypes)

        dataDetector.enumerateMatches(in: string, options: .withoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.characters.count), using: { (result, matchingFlags, pointer) in
            if(result?.resultType == .link)
            {
                if let url = URL(string: NSString(string: string).substring(with: (result?.range)!))
                {
                    if(UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url))
                    {
                        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                        } else {
                            // Fallback on earlier versions
                            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Kinja did you try this answer?

Comment: Ermm apparently i tried kumar one instead, but for now i want it to link to a view controller that i created instead, do u know the solution?

Comment: You are using NavigationController? @Kinja

Answer (score 0):

You can open URL like this or You can follow @Reinier answer

I have just edited your code @Kinja

```
// Get the metadata object.
let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
    // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
    let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
    qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

    if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
        let url = URL(string: metadataObj.stringValue)!
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
           UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
           UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
        // messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
    }
}
```

Thanks